# glUseProgram gives Invalid Operation error when trying to use a Compute Shader

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, compute-shader

I'm trying to use OpenGL in Python to play with Compute Shaders, but I have very little idea what I'm doing. I'd like to be able to send in some data, have the shader alter it, and read that data back out.  This is the code I've written so far:

```
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

import numpy as np

buffer_data = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])

compute_shader_code = """
#version 430 core

layout(std430, binding=9) buffer data{
    vec4 Data[];
};

void main() 
{
    Data[0].x = 1;
    Data[0].y = 2;
    Data[0].z = 3;
    Data[0].w = 4;
}
"""

def setup():
    pygame.init()
    window_width = 1000
    window_height = 800
    display = (window_width, window_height)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)

    test()

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def test():
    print("Creating shader program")
    compute_shader_program = -1
    shader_program = -1

    compute_shader_program = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(compute_shader_program, compute_shader_code)
    glCompileShader(compute_shader_program)
    if glGetShaderiv(compute_shader_program, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != GL_TRUE:
        raise RuntimeError(glGetShaderInfoLog(compute_shader_program))
    shader_program = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(shader_program, compute_shader_program)
    glLinkProgram(shader_program)

    if shader_program != -1:
        ssbo = -1
        print("Binding buffers")
        glUseProgram(shader_program)
        glGenBuffers(1, ssbo)
        glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 9, ssbo)
        glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo)

        print("Calling compute")
        glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1)
        glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT)

        block_index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(shader_program, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, "data", 9)
        if block_index != GL_INVALID_INDEX:
            print("I think I found the data")
        #   How do I access the data here

        glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER)


setup()
```

When I run this program I get this error:

```
  File "some location/Compute Shader Test.py", line 56, in test
    glUseProgram(shader_program)
  File "some location\Anaconda3\envs\Regression\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 402, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
  File "errorchecker.pyx", line 53, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError (src\errorchecker.c:1218)
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1282,
    description = b'invalid operation',
    baseOperation = glUseProgram,
    cArguments = (2,)
)
```

So I guess I have 2 questions. First, why am I getting this error? The shader program seems to compile just fine and on my computer it is given an integer value of 2. Am I creating it incorrectly? Is this not how you use compute shaders?

Second, how can I read data back out after the shader has been run?

Thanks a lot!

***************Update***************

After some suggestions from the comments I have it running without crashing. Now the problem is the value that comes back from the card is strange.

Updated code:

```
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

import numpy as np

buffer_data = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])

compute_shader_code = """
#version 430 core
layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;

layout(std430, binding=9) buffer data{
    vec4 Data[];
};

void main() 
{
    Data[0].x = 1;
    Data[0].y = 2;
    Data[0].z = 3;
    Data[0].w = 4;
}
"""

def setup():
    pygame.init()
    window_width = 1000
    window_height = 800
    display = (window_width, window_height)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    print(glGetString(GL_VERSION))
    test()

    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def test():
    print("Creating shader program")
    compute_shader_program = -1
    shader_program = -1

    compute_shader_program = glCreateShader(GL_COMPUTE_SHADER)
    glShaderSource(compute_shader_program, compute_shader_code)
    glCompileShader(compute_shader_program)
    if glGetShaderiv(compute_shader_program, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) != GL_TRUE:
        raise RuntimeError(glGetShaderInfoLog(compute_shader_program))
    shader_program = glCreateProgram()
    glAttachShader(shader_program, compute_shader_program)
    glLinkProgram(shader_program)
    print(glGetProgramInfoLog(shader_program))

    if shader_program != -1:
        ssbo = -1
        print("Binding buffers")
        glUseProgram(shader_program)
        glGenBuffers(1, ssbo)
        glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 9, ssbo)
        glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, ssbo)
        glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, np.ascontiguousarray(buffer_data, dtype=np.float32), GL_DYNAMIC_READ)

        print("Calling compute")
        glDispatchCompute(1, 1, 1)
        glMemoryBarrier(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BARRIER_BIT)

        block_index = glGetProgramResourceIndex(shader_program, GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BLOCK, "data", 9)
        if block_index != GL_INVALID_INDEX:
            print("I think I found the data")
        #   How do I access the data here
            result = glMapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY)
            print(result)
            print(buffer_data)
            glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER)


setup()
```

When I print result I get 2109824291840 which is obviously not what I was expecting. I would appreciate any help on how to properly read data back from the buffer. Thanks again!

Comment: i cannot test it on my computer as of now, because it doesn't have opengl > 4.3 which is required for compute shaders :-(

Comment: try to call `glGetProgramInfoLog` after `glLinkProgram` to see whether the linking has succeeded, having a number assigned to the program does not mean the program is linked successfully

Comment: @pqnet, thanks, that told me I needed to add

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1) in;

to the shader.

Now it runs but I get an invalid operation on the glUnmapBuffer(GL_SHADER_BUFFER) line.

Comment: `glUnmapBuffer` is used after `glMapBuffer`, you probably want to do `glBindBuffer(GL_SHADER_BUFFER,0)`

Comment: Does `pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)` actually net you a Core context?  Check `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`.

Comment: @genpfault, I added that after pygame.display... and it printed out b'4.6.0 NVIDIA 388.13'